# How to get the following scenario in odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-7

I have been trying with constraints recently

Consider the following field

```
'mdt': fields.datetime('Date',required=True),
```

and has a constraint

```
_constraints = [
        (_check_from_date, 'You can not choose future date :' + '['mdt']'),
        ]
```

This would display the constraint error message as follows

```
Field(s) `mdt` failed against a constraint: You can not choose future date...!
```

I wanted to concatenate the string part of the field with the error message so that it would display as

```
Field(s) `mdt` failed against a constraint: "DATE" : You can not choose future date...!
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function for your constraint:

```
_constraints = [(_check_from_date, _construct_constraint_msg, ['mdt'])]


def _construct_constraint_msg(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    for object in self.browse(cr, uid, ids,context=context):
        return _("%s : You can not choose future date...!") % object.mdt
```

you can use api 8 to do the constraint too.